# DynamoDB method returns value before complete

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb

This may not strictly be a dynamoDB question however, I have a method in a custom class that manages my DynamoDB connection. However when I call it from another class it returns before the method has complete.

I know WHY it is returning before its complete but Im not sure how to fix it. I have read about BFTask but not sure how to implement it.

There isn't a problem with the way the method is initialised, its because the database connection is finished after the return.

Any help how to restructure it would be great.

**Custom Class calling DynamoDB connection**

```
-(AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *)getRipllComments{

    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = @"######";
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = NO;
    queryExpression.indexName = @"Timestamp";

    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[CommentsDB class] expression:queryExpression] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"Failed to query a test table."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            });

        } else {

            AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput;

            paginatedOutput = task.result;

            return paginatedOutput;

        }

        return nil;
    }];

    return nil;
}
```

**Custom Method call**

```
self.DBManager = [[databaseManager alloc]init];
AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = [self.DBManager getRipllComments];
```

Comment: did you try with BFExecutor? I think if you are calling from another thread or class i.e main thread, you should use BFExecutor instead of ContinueWithBlock.

Comment: How did you initialize database connection?